# how to transfer the curl command to http post request

Tags: android, facebook, http, curl

I am using facebook object api to upload images to facebook staging service. api document is here
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/

in the doucement, it uses curl to upload the image:

curl -X POST https://graph.facebook.com/me/staging_resources -F file=@images/prawn-curry-1.jpg -F access_token=$USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

How can I achieve the same function using http post request in my android app?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
String uri = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/staging_resources";
HttpResponse response = null;
try {        
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
    MultipartEntity postEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    String picPath = (Uri.parse(picUriStr)).getPath();
    File file = new File("/data/local/tmp/images.jpg");
    postEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg"));
    postEntity.addPart("access_token", new StringBody("your access token string here"));
    post.setEntity(postEntity);
    response = client.execute(post);
}
catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "exception");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "exception");
    e.printStackTrace();
}   

HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
if (responseEntity== null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "responseEntity is null");
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to post a photo from Android, this shouldn't be any different.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putByteArray("file", data);

Request request = new Request(
    Session.getActiveSession(),
    "me/staging_resources",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST
);
Response response = request.executeAndWait();
// handle the response
```

Comment: so I guess the data here is the byte array read in from the file. It will be better if I can directly use the file path. I used the MultipartEntity and it works.

Comment: It will be nice if we can use the Request in facebook sdk with a file path